# Moving from StandardPasswordEncoder to BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, password-encryption

Are there any best practises to be considered when moving the password encoding of existing users from `StandardPasswordEncoder` to `BCryptPasswordEncoder`?

Comment: Existing passwords (which were encoded with `StandardPasswordEncoder`) can not be decoded back. It means that you can not update existing users to use BCrypt encoder -> you must use both encoders: `StandardPasswordEncoder` for existing users and `BCryptPasswordEncoder` - for new users.

Comment: Probably I could create the bcrypt-encoded password when a user logs in which still has a standard-encoded password, and then update the database, or save the new password-hash in a new field?

Comment: Yes, good idea! And I think this is the only way to replace encoders. But again - you need to support this crutch the all time while there is at least one user with old password.

Comment: Yes that's true... Users are forced to change passwords after a while so the uglyness would die out after some time. Thanks for the input.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285604/switching-from-md5-to-bcrypt-with-spring-security/31288462